# Can't get the drop down box value that is selected to show up in the next page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to rails and very excited to learn all that I can. Everything is working fine except the drop down box. The box populate correctly and has all the value that I want. But when I click "Assign" and it goes to the next page, the value that I selected in the drop down is not showing up. I understand that I need to reference it in the link and I have tried putting different value in the link, but I have still not been able to crack the code.

```
<table class="listing" summary="Subject list">
<tr class="header">
  <th><h3>Procedures</h3></th>
  <th><h3>Notes</h3></th>
  <th><h3>Assign To</h3></th>
</tr>
<% @procedures.each do |procedure| %>
<tr>
  <td><%= procedure.procedure_name %></td>
  <td><%= procedure.note %></td>     

    <td class="actions">  

    <%= collection_select(:post, :employee_id, @individuals, :id, :last_name) %>          

    <%= link_to("Assign", {:controller => 'projects', :action => 'new', :procedure_id => procedure.id}, :class => 'action new') %>

    <%= link_to("Edit", '#', :class => 'action show') %>
    <%= link_to("Delete", '#', :class => 'action edit') %>

    <td>

  </td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

It's going to a new page because you're clicking on a link. What I'm guessing you want to happen is it send the information without reloading the page. That's accomplished with AJAX but Rails simplifies it to just `remote: true`

```
<%= link_to "Assign", {:controller => 'projects', :action => 'new', :procedure_id => procedure.id}, :class => 'action new', remote: true %>
```

Also, in the terminal type rake routes and replace the hash. I'm betting it's just `new_projects_path(procedure)`

```
<%= link_to "Assign", new_projects_path(procedure_id: procedure.id), :class => 'action new', remote: true %>
```

EDIT: What you want it a form. I'm just going to skip the erb but that's simple enough (but I'll put in the equals sign for you):

```
form_for procedure.projects.new, remote: true do |f|

  = f.collection_select... #probably same as before, consult collection_select form helpers docs to be sure
  = f.hidden_field :procedure_id, value: procedure.id
  = f.submit
end
```

Like I mention below in the comments if projects#new is nested you should be able to skip the hidden field.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. On the link_to, can I leave it alone and just add a param to pass to the new action? If so, what verbiage to I add after "procedure_id => procedure.id", to get it to pass the collection_select to the new page? Again sorry if this is a dumb question

Comment: I am sorry, I should be more specific, how do I pass the parameter for the employee_id? as seen in the collection_select? Thanks

Comment: I've never used a hash in place of a route helper, but if it was taking you to the `new` page I guess you can use it. But I did edit a correction to pass the `id` as a param, assuming that project#new isn't a nested resource under `procedures`, in which case I assume the id would be send automatically. But I'd test it to make sure.

Comment: Oh, ok, give it a minute for me to edit, you just want a remote form

Comment: Hey, if that solved your issue it's customary to accept the answer.

Comment: Sorry, it has not solved my issue. What I am having a challenge with is not passing the procedure_id but this line
collection_select(:post, :employee_id, @individuals...
I can't get the employee_id to pass to the next page, in other words in the params.... Again I am very new to Ruby and Rails.. Thanks

Comment: When a user clicks the collection for employee_id, when then click "assign", I would like to pass the employee_id they selected AND the procedure_id... thanks for helping

Comment: By next page I assume you mean the controller, right? OK, get rid of the `remote: true` in form_for, and `:post` in collection_select if you're using the form builder. I misunderstood your problem was that it was loading a new page, I see that's not what you meant. What are the `params` being sent to the controller (check the logs the server is printing out). Oh, I overlooked it before but why are you sending this to `ProjectsController#new` and not `create`?